# Copy a vector to another vector in reverse order

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am new in C++.
I need to copy a vector in reverse order to another vector.

Here's how i did it :

```
int temp[] = {3, 12, 17};

vector<int>v(temp, temp+3);

vector<int>n_v;

n_v=v;
reverse(n_v.begin(), n_v.end()); //Reversing new vector
```

Is there any simple way to copy a vector in reverse order to another vector in STL?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019722/how-to-reverse-a-vector-of-strings-in-c/11019765#11019765) covers most variations on this theme, (Found by searching this site for "[c++] copy a vector in reverse order".)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply just do this:

```
vector<int>n_v (v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `reverse_iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> n_v(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Answer (score 2):

From C++20, the views can be used.

```
std::vector v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
auto result = v | std::views::reverse ;
```

Here the result can be directly iterated `8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1`.

But if still need a vector

```
std::vector rev_v(std::ranges::begin(result), std::ranges::end(result));
```

The advantage of these viewer adapters is, we can chain up multiple requirements.

For example, if the requirement says, reverse the vector, get the first four squaring them. We can do this in one statement.

```
auto result = v | std::views::reverse | std::views::take(4) | std::views::transform([](int i) { return i * i; });
```

The output is `64  49  36  25`

Comment: There is now (C++23) [`std::ranges::to<std::vector>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to) to convert the range into vector.